# Resize FabricJS canvas from VueJS child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Using VueJS and FabricJS, I'm trying to change the size of the canvas whenever the user inputs dimensions into a sidebar component. I would like the canvas size to change dynamically as the dimensions are entered.

I'm using $emit from the child to the parent, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

**SideBar.vue**

```
   <template>
     <div class="control-bar">
        <b-sidebar position="static" open >
           <b-menu-list>
               <b-menu-item label="Height">
                   <b-field>
                       <b-input v-model="height" maxlength="5" @change="emitHeight()"></b-input>
                   </b-field>
               </b-menu-item>
               <b-menu-item>
                   <b-field>
                       <b-input v-model="width" maxlength="5" @change="emitWidth()"></b-input>
                   </b-field>
               </b-menu-item>
           </b-menu-list>
        </b-sidebar>
     </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default {
      data() {
       return {
           width: '640',
           height: '480',
       }
      },
      methods: {
        emitWidth() {
           this.$emit('changeWidth', this.width)
        },
        emitHeight() {
           this.$emit('changeHeight', this.height)
        }
      },
    }
  </script>
```

**Canvas.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="columns">
        <section class="section canvas-section column auto">
            <SideBar @changeWidth="widthChange($event)" @changeHeight="heightChange($event)" />
        </section>
        <section class="section canvas-section column is-10 canvas-column">
            <canvas class="canvas" ref="can"></canvas>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {fabric } from 'fabric'
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar.vue'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            canvasHeight: '480',
            canvasWidth: '640',
            canvas: null
        }
    },
    components: {
        SideBar
    },
    methods: {
        heightChange (height) {
            this.canvasHeight = height;
            this.canvas.setHeight = this.canvasHeight;
        },
        widthChange (width) {
            this.canvasWidth = width;
            this.canvas.setWidth = this.canvasWidth;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const ref = this.$refs.can;
        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(ref);
    }
    
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .canvas-column {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .canvas {
        border: 1px solid darkgrey;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .canvas-section {
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
heightChange (height) {
    this.canvasHeight = height;
    this.canvas.setHeight = this.canvasHeight;
},
widthChange (width) {
    this.canvasWidth = width;
    this.canvas.setWidth = this.canvasWidth;
}
```

setHeight and setWidth are methods which accepts parameters.
So instead of assigning it as property, update it to use method syntax.

```
 this.canvas.setHeight(this.canvasHeight);
 this.canvas.setWidth(this.canvasWidth);
```

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setWidth
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setHeight

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fabric-js-stackoverflow-problem-4g4x2